# I'm trying to add an Event Listener for my script tag incase it aborts but won't register the "onabort" event nor abort

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a backup script but it doesn't want to register the onabort nor abort events. When I purposefully mess up my src link to make the onabort callback run it doesn't work.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('onabort',() =>{
            prompt('works:${y}')
        })   
        document.getElementById("test").src="linol.js"
```

```html
 <script id="test" ></script>
```

Comment: You would want `onerror`, not `onabort` (this is only used for video or audio elements). By the way: you need to use a backtick (`\``) instead of single quotation if you want your template to be replaced. Finally, removing the `src` tag does not cause an error. Try `<script id="test" src="4wei75></script>`.

Comment: Thanks it changed the src link but it didn't load the new script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event `onabort` [is only for media elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/abort_event). You're looking for `onerror`, which fires when a script fails to load:

```html
<script id="test" src="wae7r8456fs4786f5hdummynothingnope" onerror="this.src = 'linol.js'"></script>
```

Comment: This worked but didn't load the new script either

Comment: @HBAnimation are you sure? It inserted the script for me... try running this *after* page load: `console.log(document.getElementById("test"))`. You should see the changed `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the ['error'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event) event

Here's your updated working example:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('error', () =>{
  prompt('works:${y}');
});   
document.getElementById("test").src="linol.js"
```

```html
<script id="test"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("error",function(){
    document.getElementById("test").src="https://craigapphost.w3spaces.com/lino.js"
}) and it switched the src but didn't load the new script though

Comment: Never mind I figured it out thank you!

Comment: I just used the event listener to create a whole new script tag